# How to pixelate like this

Tags: images, resize, photo-editing, pixel, size

How do I create natural (for lack of a better word) pixelation like this from a high resolution image? (image needs to be downloaded to see what i mean) For example, can I downsize it, allow the small errors (like the blue pixels at the edges of corners and slight pixel blurring) and then bring it back up to big size whilst still containing those nice natural pixelation? if that makes sense! when I do mosaic in photoshop it looks too clean and doesnt have the kind of destruction i am looking for.

[image]

Comment: Those are jpeg compression artifacts.  If you save a jpeg and decrease the quality slider (increased compression) when exporting, you should get something similar.

Comment: Just save a jpg as a jpg....open the new jpg.. repeat. it'll keep getting worse with each iteration. Stop when you're happy.